# Seeking mosaicked global DEM?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I would like to know if there is already available mosaiced* DEM (digital elevation model) raster for the entire globe?

On [this site](https://cgiarcsi.community/data/srtm-90m-digital-elevation-database-v4-1/), they provide this data from the Shuttle Radar Topography Mission but it does not include the Arctic.

*[Mosaiced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_mosaicing) means multiple raster images are stitched together.

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks. Will do. Though I must say stack exchange is becoming so branched out from what it used to be.

Comment: "[Each of our 174 communities is built by people passionate about a focused topic.](https://stackexchange.com/) "

Answer (score 2):

The Nasa JPL hosts continent-scale mosaic DEMs (with voids corrected), and you can access using the Google Earth Engine API:

For example:
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/USGS_SRTMGL1_003

Comment: Better yet, search there for datasets *tagged* with "dem": https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/tags/dem . This includes DEMs from the Arctic and Antarctic (from Cryosat)